# Can you split the DLL in ASP.NET MVC, to deploy partial projects?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I come from a webforms background, but have been using MVC for 2 or 3 years and am happy with it.  I do however have one niggling question.  In the old webforms environment when I made a change on my test site, I could just copy the relevant file over.  In MVC, if I make a change to any code it seems like I have to build the whole project and copy the entire DLL over.  This has lots of problems:

1. The first visit to each page of the website thereafter is a bit slower.
2. I always worry that I might have made some other change in some other part of the website, which will mess things up.
3. It seems a waste copying a huge DLL file over when I've only made one small change.

Have I missed the point?  It would be a big point to miss, but I kind of hope I have.

Comment: have you tried to create new class library in same solution and add reference with copy local = true ? then replace the DLL for the class library. Also I remember there was an option for ignoring version number of the DLL added as reference.

Comment: I've thought of that, but that means I then have to divide my code into categories, and ensure there's no cross-over.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split the main dll into many parts. Even if you create a library in the solution, you can't move your action methods to that library. All your action methods that serve requests must be part of the main dll.

Comment: Thanks.  With things like this, I always wonder why other people don't encounter the same problem.  I realise Microsoft would answer that I should create a class library.